# writing user defined functions

Tags: r, function, user-defined-functions

I am new to writing functions and I'm not really sure where to start. Below is a subset of a data frame named m1 for this example. I would like to write a function that will go through the data set and extract length and depth information by number. For instance, if it encounters the number 1 it takes the length and depth and inserts them into the first row of a new data frame or vectors. It then does the same if the number equals 2 and so on.

```
       length number depth
 [1,]    109      1    10
 [2,]    109      1    10
 [3,]    109      1    10
 [4,]    109      1    10
 [5,]    109      1    10
 [6,]    109      1    10
 [7,]    109      1    10
 [8,]    109      1    10
 [9,]    109      1    10
[10,]    109      1    10
[11,]    109      1    10
[12,]    109      1    10
[13,]    107      2    10
[14,]    107      2    10
[15,]    107      2    10
[16,]    107      2    10
[17,]    107      2    10
[18,]    107      2    10
[19,]    107      2    10
[20,]    107      2    10
```

Here is an attempt at writing a function to get the output described above if the number equals 1.

```
length.fun=function(x)
{
  lengths=numeric()
  depth=numeric()
  if (x[2]==1)
  {
    lengths=x[1]
    depth=x[3]
  }
  return(cbind(depth,lengths))
}

length.fun(m1)
```

However, all I get as an output is this:

```
length.fun(m1)
   depth lengths
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: It doesn't look like a data.frame. What is the output of `class(m1)`?

Comment: What is your goal? A `data.frame` with two rows, one for `depth`, one for `lengths`. Or multiple rows, one for each unique element in `number`. Or with multiple rows, two for each unique element in `number`, one for `lengths`, one for `depth`? Please be a bit more detailed.

Comment: user1997414, it was my understanding that you want to create separate data frames (or matrices) for each value of number. Is this true. If this is true, maybe you could provide some background information about why you want to do this?

Comment: My goal is to have a data frame with two columns as suggested by @PaulHiemstra, depth and length. Each number should only have one row in this data frame. `10 109`, `10 107`, etc.

Comment: What do you mean by each number should only have one row? Given your example above, could you show us what the output should be? This would make it much easier to find an appropriate solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit:

From you comment I understand that you want to get the unique rows. Fortunately, there is a function just for this:

```
unique(m1)

#       length number depth
# [1,]     109      1    10
# [13,]    107      2    10
```

`unique(m1)[,-2]` will give you only the two columns. Use `as.data.frame` to turn a matrix into a data.frame.

---

`m1` is a matrix. A matrix is just a vector with a dimension attribute. `m1[2]` gives you the second value in the vector, that is `109`. Therefore your `if` condition is `FALSE` and you `cbind` empty vectors in your function.

This does what you want:

```
m1[m1[,2]==1,c(1,3)]
```

You should read up on matrix subsetting in R.

You can use debugging functions to inspect what happens. Here is an example:

First insert breakpoints in your function using `browser`.

```
length.fun=function(x)
{
  lengths=numeric()
  depth=numeric()
  if (x[2]==1)
  {browser("1")
    lengths=x[1]
    depth=x[3]
  }
  browser("2")
  return(cbind(depth,lengths))
}
```

Now call the function using `trace`.

```
trace(length.fun(m1))
```

You will get a prompt, that allows you to inspect the state of variables.

```
> trace(length.fun(m1))
Called from: length.fun(m1)
Browse[1]> browserText()
[1] "2"
Browse[1]> lengths
numeric(0)
Browse[1]> Q
```

As you see, the first breakpoint that is reached is the second breakpoint. Thus, the condition of the `if` construct was `FALSE` and the code inside was never executed. This is also confirmed by the value of `lengths`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: it is not clear from the question whether the data is in matrix or in dataframe form.

If it is a dataframe, then x[2] is a vector with length > 1. Therefore, your condition will test only the first element. If it is a matrix, see the explanation of @Roland.

As beginner, when writing function it is advised to go from "inside out". Namely, don't write the function first. Begin with simple code pieces. See what `m1[2]` gives. See what Boolean values are given by `m1[2]==1` (whether this is expression is TRUE or FALSE). Then try running the condition. Only when the main/key portions of your code work as expected, with specific data at hand, wrap the function around that code.

The particular function you are trying to achieve must cycle through all values in the column 2. Therefore, some sort of loop is required, e.g. `for` or `apply`.

Comment: (-1) `x[2]` is a vector of length 1.

Comment: @Roland In a matrix, yes. In a data.frame, no. m1 is a data.frame. Check it out yourself.

Comment: According to the output shown, `m1` is a matrix. If it was a data.frame, they would get a warning from the function.

Comment: @Roland That is correct. However, see the second sentence of the question. It clearly specifies the class. Is it possible that the OP has omitted the warning?

Comment: Let's see, what they say. For now I give you the 2 points back.

Comment: However, if I make m1 a data.frame, I don't get the output they show.

Comment: @Roland I don't think this is the pivotal issue in this question, really. Either it is a matrix or dataframe, the function will not work. You explain the matrix case, I explain the dataframe case. I see the value of my answer rather in the approach to function writing than in the explanation of the mistake anyway.

Comment: Well, that's true. However, an important point is that for these standard operations (like subsetting), there are build-in functions. Most user-defined functions (in particular if a loop is involved) will be slow in comparison.

Comment: @Roland chat maybe? :) Slow - agreed. It really depends on what the specific form of the result he desires, which is not very clear from the question. If it is a simple loop on `number` with single output dataframe, then simple m1[-2] would suffice. If he wants separate dataframes, it is something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the split function to split your data frame into a list of separate data frames. If your data frame is called foo then:

```
foo.split<-split(foo[,c('length','depth')],foo$number)
```

Given this list you can name each element of the list, extract the elements etc.

Note, this only works for data frames. If you have a matrix, you can convert it to a data frame using the data.frame() function.

Comment: Roland, he wrote 'Below is a subset of a data frame named m1 for this example'.

Comment: They are clearly a beginner and might not now, what they actually have there.

Comment: True, in that case they could use the data.frame function to convert their matrix to a data frame. I'll edit it.